# Push Notification for Custom Lightning component in Salesforce 1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I have created a lightning component for notification and have created a lightning tab for it and have brought it in the Salesforce 1 mobile app navigation menu.Now I want users to be notified whenever any notification comes in this custom lightning component.Is this possible?Please suggest me any article or way to achieve this.

Comment: Did you follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1GUvEjbdns and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_registration_process.htm

Comment: @SantanuBoral All the examples are using vf page to show notifications.I need a sample blog or article showing detailed steps for lightning component which I have brought in the salesforce 1 navigation menu.